# Compile SDL and GTK+ together

Tags: c, compilation, gtk, sdl, gtk3

I have been trying to compile SDL and GTK+ together on Linux, Ubuntu. The program outputs two windows, a GTK+ and in parallel an SDL one but I cannot seem to compile them together.

It seems like it is not linking to the SDL library properly. My code and the compiling flags work when running SDL and GTK+ seperately, just not together.

These are the compiling flags and error messages I am getting:

```
gcc entry.c -o entry `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `sdl2-config --cflags` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -lm -lSDL2_ttf
```

ERROR MESSAGES:

```
/tmp/cc0u3LoN.o: In function `main':
entry.c:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
/tmp/cc0u3LoN.o: In function `create_window':
entry.c:(.text+0x355): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
entry.c:(.text+0x37c): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
entry.c:(.text+0x3a1): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

THIS IS MY MAIN:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  SDL_Surface *screen;
  SDL_Event event;
  SDL_Simplewin *sw;

  create_window(sw);
  openGtkWindow();
  /*display_text(sw);*/

  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

AND THESE ARE THE LIBRARIES I AM USING IN MY HEADER:

> gtk/gtk.h , errno.h , SDL.h , stdio.h , string.h , stdlib.h , math.h, SDL_ttf.h

Comment: Where is `sdl2-config --libs` (that's your answer, btw)? But even so, what's that supposed to do? You never reach `gtk_main`. There are ways to spin gtk main loop from elsewhere though, e.g. with `gtk_main_iteration`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats such a stupid mistake! Just ran it again adding sdl2-config --libs. It basically removed most of the error messages but still won't compile as it returns: "cannot find: -lglib-2.0-lSDL2"

Comment: Graves (or `$(some-command)`) in shell/makefile instructs shell to execute given command and substitute it with this command's output. You get e.g. `-lSDL2` instead of your `sdl2-config --libs` and so on. If your resulting line contains `-lglib-2.0-lSDL2` that means you don't have a space between `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` and `sdl2-config --libs`.